# Make hyperlinks clickable in a DVI converted to PDF

Tags: pdf, urls, dvi

I have a legacy system that "generates" documentation for one of our systems.

The resulting DVI file is then converted to PDF using dvipdfm.

The DVI contains URLs, but those aren't clickable in the PDF.

I'm not sure if the hyperlinks are marked in the DVI. When the system generates HTML the links are clickable, but that markup might already be lost in the DVI and a tool might have to make everything starting with http:// clickable.

Is there such a tool ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Have a look [here](http://arxiv.org/hypertex/) which seems to explain how to achieve this. For reference also see The [`hyperref` manual](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf).
And finally: any reason not to consider going straight to a pdf with `pdftex`/`pdflatex`?

Comment: I don't really have control over the TeX input. Its generated by an old sgml2latex tool which is out of maintenance for over 10 years now. (And the input to that tool isn't real SGML either...) I was hoping there was a tool that would take the DVI and make the links clickable.

Comment: that would make things more difficult. as a starting point - the [`sgml2latex` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sgml2latex.1.html) suggests that [`linuxdoc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/linuxdoc.1.html) is now the preferred way for such a conversion - any chance to get your input running with that?

Comment: My input works with `linuxdoc -B`, but the resulting PDF is still the same.

Comment: I you can provide some snippets of your input smgl and the resulting tex files (including the beginnings of the files, i.e. minimum up to the end of the tex preamble plus first paragraph of text) then [this](http://www.ucc.ie/info/net/sgml2tex.html) might help figuring out how to add the `hyperref` package.